# Hibernate persistence slow on One-To-Many

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jboss5.x

I have a quite large object tree structure that I persist with Hibernate. This should have been persisted with the root-node first and then the children and so on. However this was not the way that Hibernate did it, it persisted the child first and than updated the reference column in the child when the parent had been persisted. This is not an optimal way of doing it so I forced the One-To-Many (JoinColum) to be not null (nullable=false).

Now it turns out that everything is even slower, much much slower. I don't understand?!

Comment: I don't think there are enough details to get any answer.

Comment: I understand that the level of details are low. However I don't have that much yet and are working on it. So to added to it all can say that if I have "nullable=false" on all my One-To-Many and Many-To-One relations the persisting takes 30 minutes. If I remove the contraint but have the same data it takes 40 seconds. I could also add that I don't have cyclic dependencies in my object-graph, it is a tree (on relations that have "cascada").

Comment: The problem is related to the way Hibernate makes inserts and updates. When using "nullable=true" (or nothing at all) Hibernate will skip the foreign key column on the insert and update it later on with an update statement. However if "nullable=false" the foreign key will be in the insert but with an incorrect value and later updated by an update statement?! This is very inefficient and something I would really like to get around (Why the difference is this big on a PostgreSQL I still do not understand?).

Comment: There is probably some other factor affecting hibernate's insertion order of operations that isn't clear from this description.

Comment: A have successfully fixed this now. Hibernate was forces into a breadth first approche when persisting data if foreign keys was not allowed to be null. One thing that also added to complexity was that the tree wasn't as "perfect" of a tree as I thought. This caused the approche to be much worse than I suspected. I relaxed the constrains somewhat on the One-To-Many relations so that Hibernate could persist in an order (bottom-up) that it found more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a bi-directional association you need to map one end as inverse (inverse attribute in xml and mappedBy if you are using annotations).